# How to mask different value field in input tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

```
<c:forEach var="attribs" items="${status.value}">
                    <input type="text" name="cust_name"
                        value="<c:out value='${attribs.value}'/>">
</c:forEach>
```

For all `values` I want to be masked something like this `AB****CD`

Comment: What will happen if some one enters only `AB`

Comment: these are edge cases.. assume all string are of length more than 5